# Potential definition

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, potential, voltage, definition

I am visiting a course for Event Engineering and I want to ask you, if following sentence is right. I have a large disagreement about it.

A measured Voltage, which is based on a point e.g. 0V, is called potential.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

A potential better has to be called a potential difference. If you are on a hill 1000 m about see and go down to a high of 800 m the potential difference is related to 200 m. If you go down to the sea, the potential difference is related to all the 1000 meters.

Usually under an electric potential one understand the potential difference to 0 V, but the statement

> A measured voltage, which is based on a point e.g. 0V, is called potential

with “e.g. 0V” is the more exact statement. The potential difference can be measured to not 0V of course. So the potential difference for two resistors in series with a 24V source is 12V for each resistor.